# Do Nginx and PHP container both need same php files?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Looking at a common docker-compose setup for a Nginx / combo like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-example:
    image: nginx:1.13-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/www
      - ./config/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  php-example:
    image: php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./www:/www
```

You find many examples like that to make sure, that if you change something in your local www folder it will be immediately picked up by a running container.

But when I do not want that and copy some php files/content etc. into the container:

1. Is it enough to create a volume of the same name for both containers and copy my files into that folder e.g. in Dockerfile?
2. Or is it even possible to not have a volume but create a directory in the container and copy the files there... and in that case: do I have to do for both nginx and php-fpm with the same files?

Perhaps my misunderstanding is around how the php-fpm container works in that combination (of course fastcgi... in conf points to the php-example:9000 standard)

My ideal solution would be to copy once and making sure that file permissions are handled.

Comment: Only the FPM container needs the php files, nginx needs the static assets (css/js/images) if any exist.